# new Proxy does not work on functions in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, v8, proxies

```
new Proxy(function() {}, {})
```

Creating a proxy to watch a function does not work on Chrome. Instead it throws an error:

```
Uncaught illegal access
```

I want to watch a function and create a proxy handler for when its properties are accessed. Seems fine in Firefox. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the Chrome devtools console trying to show the result, not the Proxy constructor itself. What version of Chrome are you using?

In the Chrome 50 console, I see this:

```
> let p = new Proxy(function(){return 6},{})
< undefined
> p
< #<Function>
Uncaught illegal access
  DebuggerScript.getFunctionScopes @ (program):4
> p()
< 6
```

So the function proxy works just fine, but the console barfs displaying it. Should be fixed in the latest Chrome versions. For now, you can just ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as @AndreasRossberg answered a Chrome limitation.
If you use same code in Firefox it works correctly and outputs as expected:

```
> let p = new Proxy(function(){return 6},{})
< undefined
> p
< function ()
> p()
< 6
```